# Searchview Filters, from retrieved Volley Library data

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-volley, searchview

I am using `Volley Library` for retrieving data from server. Now I implemented `SearchView` for filter the data. Here I used searchview for each and every `tabs`. Search query is not properly passed to adapter class.Sometimes it passes.While it pass to adapter class I need to filter the data which was retrieved from Server and need to adapt it the recycler view.

This is my code..Please help me to fix it.

**TabFragment.java**

```
public class TabFragment_1 extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener {

    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "Preference";
    Context context;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    String currentTab;
    private String query = "";
    //    private ListAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Restaurant_Beam> listSuperHeroes;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private int count = 0;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        context = getActivity();
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentTab = pref.getString("FIRST_TAB", "tab1");
        Log.e("Current Tab", currentTab);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_rv);

        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        listSuperHeroes = new ArrayList<>();

        getData();
        return view;
    }

    //This method will get data from the web api
    private void getData() {
        //Showing a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading Data", "Please wait...", false, false);
        //Creating a json array request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.DATA_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                //Dismissing progress dialog
                loading.dismiss();
                //calling method to parse json array
                parseData(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });

        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    private void parseData(JSONArray array) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Restaurant_Beam superHero = new Restaurant_Beam();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                superHero.setStr_categoryName(json.getString(Config.CATEGORY_NAME));
                superHero.setStr_productName(json.getString(Config.PRODUCT_NAME));
                superHero.setStrPrice(json.getInt(String.valueOf(Config.PRICE)));
                superHero.setImageUrl(json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE_URL));
                superHero.setTAB_NAME(json.getString(Config.TAB_NAME));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (superHero.getTAB_NAME().contains(currentTab)) {
                listSuperHeroes.add(superHero);
                adapter = new CardAdapter(listSuperHeroes, context);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        System.out.println("Restaurant Tab onQueryTextSubmit =" + "");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        System.out.println("Restaurant Tab onQueryTextSubmit =" + query);
        ((CardAdapter) recyclerView.getAdapter()).setFilter(query);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        System.out.println("Restaurant Tab onQueryTextSubmit =" + newText);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        final SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
}
```

**CardAdapter.java:**

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<Restaurant_Beam> restaurant_prducts;
    Config config;
    Bitmap bmp;
    boolean success = false;
    ArrayList<String> CATEGORYNAME;
    ArrayList<String> ITEMNAME;
    ArrayList<String> ITEM_PRICE;
    ViewHolder vHolder;
    ArrayList<String> visibleObjects;
    ArrayList<String> wordList;

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;

    public CardAdapter(List<Restaurant_Beam> superHeroes, Context context) {
        super();

        this.restaurant_prducts = superHeroes;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Restaurant_Beam restaurant_beam = restaurant_prducts.get(position);

        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(context).getImageLoader();
        imageLoader.get(config.IMAGE_URL + restaurant_beam.getImageUrl() + ".jpg", ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.productImage, R.drawable.image_1, R.drawable.image_1));  //android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert

/*        holder.productImage.setImageUrl(config.IMAGE_URL + restaurant_beam.getImageUrl() + ".jpg", imageLoader);
        holder.txt_itemName.setText(restaurant_beam.getStr_productName());
        holder.txt_categoryName.setText(String.valueOf(restaurant_beam.getStr_categoryName()));
        holder.txt_Price.setText(String.valueOf(restaurant_beam.getStrPrice()));
        holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);*/

        String IMAGE_URL = config.IMAGE_URL + restaurant_beam.getImageUrl() + ".jpg";
        String ITEM_NAME = restaurant_beam.getStr_productName();
        String CATEGORY_NAME = restaurant_beam.getStr_categoryName();
        String PRICE = String.valueOf(restaurant_beam.getStrPrice());

        holder.productImage.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, imageLoader);
        holder.txt_itemName.setText(ITEM_NAME);
        holder.txt_categoryName.setText(CATEGORY_NAME);
        holder.txt_Price.setText(PRICE);
        holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        ITEMNAME = new ArrayList<>();
        CATEGORYNAME = new ArrayList<>();
        ITEM_PRICE = new ArrayList<>();

        ITEMNAME.add(ITEM_NAME);
        CATEGORYNAME.add(CATEGORY_NAME);
        ITEM_PRICE.add(PRICE);

        Log.e("Filter", String.valueOf(ITEMNAME) + "  ..." + CATEGORYNAME);

        holder.productImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), ProductActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("itemName", holder.txt_itemName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("categoryName", holder.txt_categoryName.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("Price", Integer.parseInt(holder.txt_Price.getText().toString()));
                view.getContext().startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        holder.iv_settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        holder.viewDetail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked ViewDetail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        holder.addToCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked AddToCart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        holder.checkOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Clicked CheckOut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.e("Restaurant Size", String.valueOf(restaurant_prducts
                .size()));
        return restaurant_prducts.size();
    }

    public void setFilter(String query) {
        Log.e("Adapter Query", query);
        String[] stringArray = new String[restaurant_prducts.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < restaurant_prducts.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("I am inside ForLoop" + " " + i);
            stringArray[i] = restaurant_prducts.get(i).toString();
        }
        wordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray));

        List<Restaurant_Beam> list = new ArrayList<>(stringArray.length);

//        list.addAll(wordList);
//        restaurant_prducts.add(list);
//
//        for(String s : stringArray){
//            restaurant_prducts.add()
//        }

        Log.e("String array", wordList.toString());

        Log.e("Adapter Query", String.valueOf(ITEMNAME) + " " + CATEGORYNAME + " " + ITEM_PRICE + " " + stringArray);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

//    public void flushFilter() {
//        visibleObjects=new ArrayList<>();
//        visibleObjects.addAll(allObjects);
//        notifyDataSetChanged();
//    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public NetworkImageView productImage;
        public TextView txt_categoryName;
        public TextView txt_itemName, txt_Price;
        public CardView cardlist_item;
        public ImageView iv_settings;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;
        public Button viewDetail, addToCart, checkOut;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            iv_settings = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_settings);
            cardlist_item = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardlist_item);
            txt_itemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_itemName);
            txt_Price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Price);
            txt_categoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_categoryName);
            productImage = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productImage);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearTransparent);
            viewDetail = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.butViewDetail);
            addToCart = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.but_addTCart);
            checkOut = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.butCheckOut);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your onQuerryTextSubmit as follows

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    System.out.println("Restaurant Tab onQueryTextSubmit =" + query);
    adapter.setFilter(query);
    return true;
}
```

Also initialize your adapter and set it to your recycler view in oncreate. After fetching your data you can add it to your arraylist and call adapter.notifydatasetchanged. This way only one arraylist will be present and your onquerytext submit will always be called and data change will be reflected.

Also this is not the right way to filter data as here filtering is done on main thread, Your custom adapter should implement Filterable. Have a look at it here   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html